# SSRS 2016 - Hide Page Headers in HTML render and Show in Print Render

Tags: reporting-services, render

In MS SSRS 2016, I need to Hide PAGE Header in HTML view and Display PAGE Header in Print and PDF renders.  My current research says I can't, anyone out there have a hack/work around?

"When present, the header and footer is rendered at the top and bottom of every page within the usable page area." - Ref:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255244.aspx

I can suppress the header on the first and the last page, but I can't render the report in HTML without Page header and in PDF/Print with Page Header without having two RDLs (not an optimal solution).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't manually show/hide header on any page you want by design of SSRS.
The only thing you can do is to hide report items in header, but header will still take some place on page.

To vary visibility depending on what render format you use, you can use RenderFormat.Name and RenderFormat.IsInteractive globals (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255216.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

F.e. this will hide header report items in all formats except PDF (expression set for Hidden property of report items):

```
=(Globals!RenderFormat.Name <> "PDF")
```

Comment: I ended up using:  =IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "PDF" or Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "IMAGE", FALSE, TRUE) but it's the same concept.  Thank you!